# React-Native Clipboard image and text

Tags: image, react-native, clipboard

The main idea is to save an image to clipboard, but I want to add a Text to it.

Something like this:

```
<ImageBackground source={{uri: image}}>
  <Text>TEXT</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Then the user should be able to paste wherever he want the Image with the text on it.

I saw a library called gl-react that solves the problem to create images together with a text, but it's very complex and I could not find a way to clipboard images for Android and iOS yet. Is there any other possibility?